# GZipStream compression not working

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I'm trying to read in a file and compress it using GZipStream, like this:

```
using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);

            Debug.WriteLine(
                "Compressed from {0} to {1} bytes", 
                fileStream.Length, 
                outStream.Length);

            // "outStream" is utilised here (persisted to a NoSql database).
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `outStream.Length` always shows 10 bytes. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried calling `gzipStream.Close()` after the `fileStream.CopyTo` line (as suggested in other forums) but this seems to close `outStream` too, so the subsequent code that uses it falls over.

Comment: According to [the msdn][1] there's no reason to trust too much the Stream.length proprety, which may or may not be implemented. Did you check by other means that the outstream obtained is incorrect ?


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN says: `The write operation might not occur immediately but is buffered until the buffer size is reached or until the Flush or Close method is called.`

In other words, the fact that all the Write operations are done doesn't mean the data is already in the `MemoryStream`. You have to do `gzipStream.Flush()` or close the gzipStream first.

Example:

```
using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(
                "Compressed from {0} to {1} bytes", 
                fileStream.Length, 
                outStream.Length);

        // "outStream" is utilised here (persisted to a NoSql database).
    }
}
```

Also, ideally, put it outside of the FileStream as well - you want to close files as soon as you can, rather than waiting for some other processing to finish.

Comment: I suspected a lack of flushing to be the culprit at first, but the [docs on `GZipStream.Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly state that the "current implementation of this method has no functionality", closing the stream is indeed the only option.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: ILSpy seems to confirm that. Wow, that's a bit under the belt. I guess they didn't have a way to implement it, since it can't work incrementally, you probably need to have all of the data compressed and written at once.

Comment: That didn't work - wrapping a using around `fileStream.CopyTo()` (or indeed closing gzipStream after the CopyTo, as mentioned in my question) results in `outStream` also closing, making it unusable in later lines.

Comment: @AndrewStephens: Yes, that's what the third parameter of the GZipStream constructor is for - if you use `new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true)`, it should leave the outStream open. Don't forget to rewind the `MemoryStream` (`outStream.Position = 0;`).

Comment: The third parameter did the trick, thanks! Marked as answered.